# My loop is stopping but cant figure out why

Tags: command-line, bash

Here is the situation ... I have a program that I'm running in wine. This program will sometimes hang.. I wanted to create a 'monitoring script' to watch it and kill and restart it if it hangs. I have gotten it to find the process and kill it if it hangs but the script stops at that point without finishing .. the finishing would be to sleep for 30 seconds then launch the program again .. but instead .. the script just stops

First of all I will say that Im very bad at writing stuff like this ... this is from googling stuff and slapping it into a file and trying to get it to do what I want :D

Here is what I have .. its a bit sloppy and probably can be cleaned up some ...

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

CPU_USAGE_THRESHOLD="120"
TOPPROCESS="0"
i="1"
re='^[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$'

while [ $i -eq 1 ]; do
         MYPROCESS=$(ps aux --sort=-pcpu | grep -v %CPU | head -n 1 | cut -d"." -f1 | cut -d" " -f7)
         MYPROCESS2=$(ps aux --sort=-pcpu | grep -v %CPU | head -n 1 | cut -d"." -f1 | cut -d" " -f6)
if ! [[ $MYPROCESS2 =~ $re ]] ; then
          >&2;
     else
     if [ "$MYPROCESS2" -gt "1" ]; then
        TOPPROCESS="$MYPROCESS2"
        echo "the calculated top process2 is $TOPPROCESS" 
        echo "the usage threshold is $CPU_USAGE_THRESHOLD";
     fi
fi
if ! [[ $MYPROCESS =~ $re ]] ; then
          >&2;
     else
     if [ "$MYPROCESS" -gt "1" ]; then
        TOPPROCESS="$MYPROCESS"
        echo "the calculated top process is $TOPPROCESS" 
        echo "the usage threshold is $CPU_USAGE_THRESHOLD"; 
     fi
fi 
if [ "$TOPPROCESS" -gt "$CPU_USAGE_THRESHOLD" ]; then 
    exec pkill SAMBC.exe;
    echo "process killed"
        sleep 30 
        exec wine C:\\SAMBC\\SAMBC.exe
        sleep 60
        i="1"
 else
    sleep 60
    i="1"
    fi
done
```

The result of this seems like it stops at killing the process... I get this as a result if i run this from a command prompt.

```
{~}:$ monitorsam
the calculated top process2 is 121
the usage threshold is 120
{~}:$
```

It seems to stop after the kill because it doesn't `echo "process killed"`
The reason I have process and process2 is for some reason the value I need will show up on one or the other .. I think it depends on what its PID is.

Like I say, I'm very bad at this stuff .. I don't really fully understand the code I just copied it off google searches and found the errors and corrected them using google .. but .. still really don't understand fully .. just a minor understanding ... it is probably some semicolon thing or something I'm missing but I tried all I can think of.

It kills the process when it hangs .. but doesn't start it again and doesn't continue to run the monitorsam script ... I want it to restart the program and continue to monitor it so it can kill it and restart it again if it hangs again.

lol sorry for the book but I wanted to make sure I gave all the information I could :D

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Install shellchecker and use that to check your code!

Comment: thanks for adding that again .. sorry .. the other guy was getting all bent out of shape because I posted on a different section of the forum ... I was able to delete it there so its not cross-posted anymore .. lol I was going to check it out and thank you even if you didn't post again :D

Comment: That other guy is a veteran on this site his advice are usually life savers :-)

Comment: Well you were much more help than he was.. if you post it as an answer I will mark it as the solution ... that did give me what I needed to fix the issue. Thanks. I wasn't aware of shellchecker :D .. I needed to remove the two `exec` from the beginning of the entries to keep the script running

Comment: The other guy finds it annoying when people can't even be bothered to wait for more than 20 minutes before spamming questions on other sites.

Comment: yeah I suppose but that wasn't the case here .. I posted it in the wrong place .. I normally post here but its been a while .. then I found this again .. and realized this is where I wanted it posted ... it wasn't because I was spamming it .. it was just a mistake .. here I have a 1681 rep .. there I have a 101 rep .. I just had the wrong spot and didn't realize it at first :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

- `i` is always `1` in your script, AFAICT. So there's no point in using it, and it's simpler to do:

  ```
  while true; do
  ...
  done
  ```
- You're `exec`ing `pkill` and `wine`. `exec` replaces the current shell with the command to be executed, so your script effectively ends when it `exec`'s anything. Just do `pkill SAMBC.exe` and `wine C:\\SAMBC\\SAMBC.exe`. The `wine` command may need to be sent to the background: `wine C:\\SAMBC\\SAMBC.exe &`.
- If you want to get the CPU usage of a specific process, it's easier if you use `pgrep` to get the PID and `ps` to get just the CPU usage:

  ```
  process_usage=$(ps -o pcpu= $(pgrep SAMBC.exe) | sed 's/\..*//')
  ```

  The `sed` command strips away trailing decimals.

Combining and simplifying:

```
#!/bin/bash

CPU_USAGE_THRESHOLD="120"

while true; do
    proc_usage=$(ps -o pcpu= $(pgrep SAMBC.exe) | sed 's/\..*//')

    if (( proc_usage > CPU_USAGE_THRESHOLD )); then 
        pkill SAMBC.exe;
        echo "process killed"
        sleep 30 
        wine C:\\SAMBC\\SAMBC.exe &
    fi
    sleep 60
done
```

Comment: thank you .. sorry I got a bit annoyed at your first response .. again I made a small mistake ... not worth a negative mark ... this is much cleaner and functions as I wanted it to ... as I said .. I was just grabbing code and trying to modify it to make it work .. with not a lot of knowledge of the code itself .. I wish I could also give a bit of credit to  George Udosen for suggesting shellchecker because I did see that you needed to remove the `exec` and did get the sloppy code to work with his help .. but yours is cleaner and probably more stable .. thanks and sorry again